# Want to control Quadcopter motion in real environment. Need to simulate the motion. Best simulation tool?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am student of Computer science and my final project bout robotics i need help for motion about ROS and its motion planing liberary and Algorithum which is best for me  to implement ation..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217545/i-want-to-control-the-motion-of-quad-copter-in-real-environment.but-first-i-want-to-simulate-the-motion-.so-question-is-what-is-the-best-tool-for-simulation-and/) by [M imran](https://answers.ros.org/users/23352/m-imran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would help if you would proof read your question -- the title even cuts off at the middle of a sentence :)

But in general, Gazebosim (gazebosim.org) is a very good, open-source, free robot simulation tool that plays nicely with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) with karma: 287 on 2015-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0